# Extending the kernel's 4MB limit for memory allocations using DMA api - dma_alloc_coherent

Tags: linux, dma

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and I'd like to use dma_alloc_coherent to allocate a DMA buffer (non-cached) that is larger than 4MB. When I attempt to do this, the call returns a NULL. I've tried the kernel flags CONFIG_DMA_CMA, etc. to enable allocation via the contiguous memory allocator.  I see the CMA memory being reserved, and I see the cma_allocator allocating the memory, but I still can't get beyond 4MB even though the memory has been reserved for my driver via the CMA allocator.

Answer (score 0):

CONFIG_DMA_CMA is a kernel compilation flag. Unless you know your kernel has compiled with this. Otherwise, you need a customized kernel. It seems that major release of both RHEL and Ubuntu don't enable this option.